# Multi-lingual CSS increment counter

Tags: css

How do you change the language in which a CSS counter displays when using alphabetical characters?

```
.outer {
    counter-increment:question;
}
.inner {
    content:counter(question, lower-alpha) ".";
}
```

Comment: Is that CSS? First time I'm seeing smth like that...

Comment: Can you post the related markup too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) settings (there's a whole list on that MDN page):

```
li {
    content:counter(question, lower-alpha) ".";
    list-style-type: lower-armenian;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/543aL6my/

Which gives:

[image]

Note that the case will follow whatever the `list-style-type` is, even though you've passed it to `counter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a [language selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) to target different languages:

```
inner:lang(it) {
    content:counter(question, lower-alpha) ".";
}
```

obviously you'd need to also modify markup but it souldn't be too difficult.